# Using Pyodbc with SQL server, regexp function not being recognized

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, regex, pyodbc

I am using Pyodbc to pull from a Microsoft SQL server. The REGEXP function in the SQL query is not being recognized. I'm not a strong SQL user but this seems pretty straight forward, I've tried many different syntax, nothing is working. The LIKE function worked for a single string, but I think it's different this regex.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
   conn = None
   cursor = None
   try:
       conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                      ,SERVER='###########'
                      ,DATABASE='####', UID='#####', PWD='#####')
    
    sql = "select top 5 * from dataset where (lower(variable) regexp '(^(total|)revenue(.|..|)$)') "
    
    data = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
    print (data)
    
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
         print('ERR', e)
    finally:
         if cursor is not None: cursor.close()
         if conn is not None: conn.close()
```

The returned error:

```
 pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select top 5 * from dataset where (lower(variable) regexp '(^(total|)revenue(.|..|)$)') ': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'regexp'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I don't have much info on the SQL server, but I am using python3.5.

### Update:

I guess the answer is that REGEX is not supported on this server and a LIKE function is the only option.

Thanks

Comment: If you skip the WHERE clause, do you get any data returned?

Comment: If you run the exact query on the server with SSMS or sqlcmd, do you get any data returned?

Comment: @jarlh Here was the error w/o Where: pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select top 5 *...

Comment: @Parfait It's hard to explain, but I don't have the MS SQL program. I can say the other queries work fine, including the LIKE function. Some reason REGEXP does not.

Comment: That could be the ODBC driver software as usually drivers support ANSI-SQL (the standard SQL) which includes `LIKE`. `REGEXP` is a SQL Server-specific (ANSI-plus) method.

Comment: Wait ... your query fails without `WHERE`? Please post that **full** traceback in the body of your post (not comments).

Comment: @Parfait Maybe I'm wrong to say "fail".  pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select top 5 * from dataset (lower(variable) regexp '(^(total|)revenue(.|..|)$)')': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'regexp'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server's regex is very limited. You can create your own regex function or use [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
 but either way, SQL Server does not recognize the 'regexp' function you're using.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) are some LIKE examples

So maybe what you're looking for is:

```
select top 5 * from dataset where (lower(variable) LIKE '%revenue%')
```

If you were to create your own regexp function, then you can test your regex using [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have used this data before so I know the regex is correct. I just have not connected to the server for a pull. Will LIKE work as a regex?

Comment: yes the regex may be correct, but sql server doesn't have a regex function and if the data is in a sql server, then you'll have to use LIKE. Yes, LIKE works like regex, but a lot more general with it's string matching